# Azure Event Hub's Python SDK and JavaScript SDK no longer working?

Tags: azure-eventhub

So I've been using Azure Event Hubs for about a year now via Python, C# and JavaScript. Recently (week and a half), Python and JavaScript stopped working, with post requests returning 40100 unauthorized. Is anyone else having this issue as well? Was there some kind of update in the way you have to send post requests into Azure Event Hubs? Nothing in any of my previous apps have changed.

Python Azure SDK:
azure 0.10.2
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/azure/0.10.2

JavaScript Azure Service Bus SDK
https://github.com/ddobric/ServiceBusJavaScriptSdk

I've tried creating Event Hubs on two separate Azure accounts, @hotmail and a corporate subscription. I've given every access, from Event Hub level send policy, to manage policy, to Service Bus level RootManagedAccess Keys. None of these work.

I just tested this app, and it too is no longer able to send to an Event Hub. It's a connect-the-dots MSDN application for TI Sensor Tags.
https://github.com/sudheshk/TISensorToEventHub_WindowsForm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell a SAS update to Event Hubs broke the publishing connection to Event Hubs. Looks like it got fixed today. Everything is working as intended once again.